# How to solve this differential equation in sympy?

Tags: sympy

I want to solve this differential equation in sympy:

```
f'(x) = f(x+1)
```

I try this:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
f = Function("f")
f_ = Derivative(f,x)
dsolve(f_(x) - f(x+1), f(x))
```

but get an error: "'Derivative' object is not callable".

When I replace "f_(x)" by "f_", I get a different error: "TypeError: doit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'".

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to differentiate after providing an argument.
The following works for me:

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
f = Function("f")
f_ = Derivative(f(x),x)
dsolve(f_ - f(x+1), f(x))
```

#### Sidenote: Solution to your actual problem

What you have is essentially a DDE, just with the time pointing in the wrong direction. The typical form of the DDE would be *g'(t) = −g(t−1).* With [this module of mine](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcdde), we can solve this numerically:

```
from jitcdde import y, t, jitcdde
from numpy import arange

f = [-y(0,t-1)]
DDE = jitcdde(f)

DDE.constant_past([1.0])

DDE.step_on_discontinuities()
times = arange(0,1000,0.1) + DDE.t
solution = [(time,DDE.integrate(time)[0]) for time in times]
```

It seems that no matter how we initialise the past, the solutions eventually converge to something of the form exp(*a·t*)·sin(*b·t*) with some constants *a* and *b* specified below. In fact if instead of `DDE.constant_past([1.0])` we use

```
a = -0.318131477176434
b =  1.33723563936212
DDE.past_from_function([exp(a*t)*sin(b*t)])
```

the solution matches exp(*a·t*)·sin(*b·t*) extremely well.

Comment: Okay... now I do not get an error, but I also do not get a solution --- just a re-iteration of the problem... I get $f(x) = C1 + \int f(x+1) dx$

Comment: Both of you might be interested in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61818/how-to-solve-differential-equations-of-the-form-fx-fx-a.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: See the above.

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me we're on a hiding to nowhere. **This is not a useful answer.**

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> f = Function('f')
>>> var('x')
x
>>> Eq(f(x).diff(x,x)-f(x+1))
Eq(-f(x + 1) + Derivative(f(x), x, x), 0)
>>> dsolve(_,f(x))
Eq(f(x), C1 + x*(C2 + Integral(f(x + 1), x)) - Integral(x*f(x + 1), x))
>>> latex(_)
'f{\\left (x \\right )} = C_{1} + x \\left(C_{2} + \\int f{\\left (x + 1 \\right )}\\, dx\\right) - \\int x f{\\left (x + 1 \\right )}\\, dx'
```

[As a graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgwgh.jpg) (having tried various ways of putting the mathematical representation here.)